# how to verify user only with uid and access_token (facebook)

Tags: facebook

The problem is how to verify user only with uid and accessToken.

graph.facebook.com/100000726976284?access_token=xxxxxx

For example, is there any simple way to check if user 100000726976284's access token is xxxxxx.

I guess the 'verified' filed is the key.

Only when I put correct xxxxxx(which is of that user), I could see verified=true in the response.

Answer (score 0):

graph.facebook.com/me will get you info on whichever current user matches the access token (or an error if the token is invalid)

Answer (score 0):

Paste your access token here:  https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug

it will tell you all the permissions granted for that particular token as well as other meta data.